# Mathematica, combine ContourPlot3D and ListPointPlot3D

Tags: function, plot, 3d, wolfram-mathematica

I would like to combine a 3-dimensional function plot with some 3D Points. Some lines that work separately are:

`D3Plot= ContourPlot3D[x^2+y^2+z^2== 2, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0,2},  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[1*(1 - z)]]]`

and:

`atest3D = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}};`

However, I get some problems when combining them together:

`Show[atest3D,D3Plot,AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}, {0, 3}}]`

Is there any way to get this to work or some other way to show these two plots together?

Comment: try `Graphics3D@Point@atest3D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Show[D3Plot, Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.1], Point[atest3D]}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is there also any way to make the points always viewable, also if they are on the other side of the surface?

Comment: try Opacity (if you have a new question, post it as a question. )